# When/how does a client timeout connection in Blazor server?

Tags: .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

As per the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/signalr?view=aspnetcore-3.1&pivots=server#reflect-the-connection-state-in-the-ui-2):

> When the client detects that the connection has been lost, a default UI is displayed to the user while the client attempts to reconnect. If reconnection fails, the user is provided the option to retry.

My question is, when exactly does this client disconnection happen? Is it when a a session timeouts, a SignalR disconnection, internet disconnection, or something else?

If this is not due to a session time out, then how can we implement a session timeout in Blazor server for a user that's inactive for, let's say 30mins?

Comment: I was able to get this technique working. Let me know if you take a stab and get stuck :) https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/blazor/event-handling/how-do-you-initiate-automatic-logout-when-a-user-is-inactive-in-blazor

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look in your browsers dev tools. SignalR is constantly exchanging bytes with the server. When the exchange fails, you will be disconnected. This happens when no conncetion to your server is available.

The session timeout needs to implemented by yourself.